# setting stdin to wide character orientation in Python extension module

Tags: python, input, python-c-extension, widechar

In a C Python extension module I'm using a library which does **`fwide(stdin,1)`**. This is causing an **`EOFError`** when i call **`input()`** in Python code. When i avoid `fwide(stdin,1)` in module's C code, the python code works fine.

The question is, is it possible to make python work with wide char `stdin`, or is it a must to leave `stdin` in narrow character mode for Python? Is this a bug in Python (it does not seem to mind if *stdout* is set to wide or narrow)?

This is Python 3, i don't know if python 2 has the same behavior.